# Floated elements should be on same line but render on two lines

Tags: html, css

My h2 text in `statistic2 div` is not aligning to the right of the `statistic1 h2 text`

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="statistics">
<div class="statistic1"><h2>Top 100 Highest Number of Comments</h2></div>
<div class="statistic2"><h2>Top 100 Highest Number of Comments</h2></div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.statistics {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  font: 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;   
}
.statistic1 {
  width:50%;
  border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  float:left;   
}
.statistic2 {
  width:50%;
}
.statistics .statistic h2 {
  font: 24px/24px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
  color: #606060;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

And here is the output:

[image: misaligned divs]

Comment: add border-box: box-sizing property to class with border which is "static1", here is an explanation of box-model https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing

Comment: @Smile0ff i dont see how setting a width and height property has to do with floating a div to the right. I tried your suggestion and added `box-sizing:border-box` to the class `statistic1` it did not work.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwygrp - here you go

Comment: @Smile0ff - you are cheating. All you did in your codepen is floating both of the elements to left, the border-box is not even needed for that. ;-)

Comment: no, you dont right, you set 50% width to both divs and then add +1px border so now your total width is 100% + 1px

Comment: @jkushner - Leave everything as is, and either set the `width` of `statistic2` to `100%` or do not set a `width` for `statistic2` at all and watch what happens. ;-)

Comment: what you trying to achieve? default value of width for block elem is 100%

Comment: @Smile0ff - You got it.